# Problems with collisions (using vector of instances)

Tags: c++

I wrote a for loop to check every instance of the class Wall, only the the last instance in the vector properly works

hybrid.h

```
 void reactTo(Player* other)
 {
     if (react)
     {
         if ((other->back<front && other->front > front) && (other->y > foot && other->y < head))
         {
             other->goAhead[0] = false;
         }
         else
         {
             other->goAhead[0] = true;

             if ((other->front >= back) && other->back < back && other->y > foot && other->y < head)
             {
                 other->goAhead[1] = false;
             }
             else
             {
                 other->goAhead[1] = true;
             }
         }
     }
     if (other->foot <= head && other->head >= head && other->x > back && other->x < front)
     {
         other->goAhead[2] = false;
     }
     else
     {
         other->goAhead[2] = true;
         if ((other->head >= foot) && other->foot < foot && foot && other->x > back && other->x < front)
         {
             other->goAhead[3] = false;
         }
         else
         {
             other->goAhead[3] = true;
         }
     }
     if (other->front > back && other->back <= front && other->head < head && other->foot > foot)
     {
         R = 0;
     }
     else
     {
         R = 1;
     }
 }
```

source.cpp

````
#include"hybrid/hybrid.h"

int main()
{
   setWindowSize(1500, 600);

   makeSequenceWall();//push back 5 Wall constructor

   Player p(300, 300,30,30,0.5,0,1,0);
   //------------
   slWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "HYBRID", false);
   while (!slShouldClose())
   {
               //----------
       p.move();
       p.render();//render the player

       
       for (int i = 0; i != 5; i++)//check the collision
       {
           wallSeq.at(i).reactTo(&p);
       }

       
       for (itr = wallSeq.begin(); itr != wallSeq.end();itr++)//render the wall
       {
           itr->render();
       }
       
       slRender();
   
   }
   slClose();
   return 0;
}

```
````

Answer (score 1):

> only the the last instance in the vector properly works

Yes, it looks like `void reactTo(Player* other)` only really takes into consideration stuff that happens with "this wall": it will overwrite in the player whatever happened with the "previous wall" that was checked.

You probably need to "reset" the data in your player at the beginning of each frame, then in your wall-check code, check *also* what happened with the previous wall checks (e.g. check if `other->goAhead[X]` has already been set to `false`, and if it has, don't set it to `true`). Or maybe set everything to `true` (`goAhead[X] = true;`) at the beginning of each frame, and only toggle the values to `false` if they must (i.e. don't set them to `true` in the collision-checking function).

Comment: I followed what you said, and so I created a array called listToGetBlocked, if it is true will make goAhead[X] true only if currentCollided is equal to current wall's Id, that was the solution :D

Comment: I meant "make goAhead[X] false'